# SQL Server Native Client 11.0: Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2016

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
    var config = {
        driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
        connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=DESKTOP-QUUGSCT\SQLEXPRESS;Database=nodedb;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
       // CONNECTION_NAME = "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog="CatalogName";Data Source="Production_Server_Name;""
    };
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
        return pool.request().query("Select * From dbo.test")
    }).then(result => {
        let rows = result.recordset
        res.status(200).json(rows);
        sql.close();
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: `${err}` })
        sql.close();
    });

});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

I used this code nodejs to connect MSSql connection string in windows authentication mode. I try to run this program I got error like this

```
{
   "message":"ConnectionError: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. "
}
```

I enabled all pipe and tcp ports.

Comment: Allow remote connection to this server checked?

Comment: Yes im allowed remote connection in my MSSQL Server 2016

Comment: sql server browser start

Comment: Yes im started..

Comment: var edge = require('edge');
var params = {
    connectionString: "Server=DESKTOP-QUUGSCT\SQLEXPRESS;Database=tempdb;Integrated Security=True",
    source: "Select * From dbo.test"
};
var getData = edge.func('sql', params);

getData(null, function (error, result) {
    if (error) { console.log(error); return; }
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
    else {
        console.log("No results");
    }
});

Comment: Im tryed this code also.But not work for me

Comment: SQL Server Services running? Firewall?

Comment: MSSSQL Server Services running. Port1433 enabled Inbound rules. But im not checked this path  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.<InstanceName>\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=DESKTOP-QUUGSCT\SQLEXPRESS;Database=nodedb;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
```

you may need to change server name `DESKTOP-QUUGSCT\SQLEXPRESS`

to `DESKTOP-QUUGSCT\\SQLEXPRESS`